# How can i run multiple .bat files simultaneously using python subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, parallel-processing, subprocess

So i have this block of code:

```
def run_batch(parameter):
    print(subprocess.run(f'cmd.exe /c *the path to the .bat file1 goes here {parameter}', shell=True, capture_output=True, check=True))
    print(subprocess.run(f'cmd.exe /c *the path to the .bat file2 goes here {parameter}', shell=True, capture_output=True, check=True))
    print(subprocess.run(f'cmd.exe /c *the path to the .bat file2 goes here {parameter}', shell=True, capture_output=True, check=True))
```

They are run in a for loop untill the list is empty:

```
for value in the_list_of_parameters:
        run_batch()
```

I want to send this 3 .bat files simultaneously, wait for them to complete and then send the next value untill the list is empty.

If i run the function as i wrote it it won't send the commands as bulk, it will send them one by one and it will wait for 1st one to finish the execution, the 2nd one to finish the execution, etc. untill all of them are run individually and then i can take the 2nd value from the list_of_parameters and send it to all the batches.

I tried using Popen too, but Popen send them as bulk but doesn't wait for them to be finished and send another values from the list_of_parameters. In the real scenario this is a BIG NO NO.

Can you please help me? I'm opened to other sugestions for different modules as long as they acomplish my scenario. I'm using Python 3.9.1.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: `subprocess.Popen()` should have done the job.  I suspect you did something with the first `Popen` result that required waiting for the process to finish before creating the second one.

Comment: 'Popen( f"cmd.exe /c *the path to the .bat file* {parameter}", stderr=STDOUT, stdout=PIPE, shell=True, encoding='utf8')', can you please give me a hint of how should I use Popen to accomplish my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution but you can use python `threading` module to run multiple `.bat` or `.cmd` files. For example:

```
import threading
import os

done1 = 0
done2 = 0

res1 = 0
res2 = 0

def bat1():
    global done1, res1
    res1 = os.system("bat1.bat")
    done1 = 1
def bat2():
    global done2, res2
    res2 = os.system("bat2.bat")
    done2 = 1

ths = (threading.Thread(target=bat1),
       threading.Thread(target=bat2))

for thread in ths:
    thread.start()

while not (done1 and done2):
    # some code to do when executing bat files

# some code after execution of all bat files
```

You can also arguments to function call by adding `args` argument:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=function, args=("Tuple of arguments", "String"))
```

Comment: I tried using threading but after reading some documentation and watch some tutorials on YouTube I understand that at some point in time some kind of concurrency will appear between threads. I'm trying to avoid this as much as I can because this script will be run on production. Thank you anyway I will consider using your solution if I can't find any solution for the scenario that I wrote.